# How do I resize,scale or magnify the distances between points plotted in OpenGl

Tags: python, opengl, scaling, points

I am trying to generate a map which is given latitudes and longitudes as input.I am fairly new to OpenGL. I need to regenerate the map based on the points given, but to make it look decent it needs to be scaled proportionately to a size so that it can be viewed appropriately. The map looks very clustered. Any ideas on how to scale the map so that it may fit the window size.
[image]

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

import math

def initFun():
    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0)
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0, 0.0)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluOrtho2D(0,700,0,700)

def displayFun():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0)
    xpts=[]
    ypts=[]
    N=len(newlist)
    for i in range(0,N):
        xpts.append(float(newlist[i][4]))
        ypts.append(float(newlist[i][5]))

    glBegin(GL_POINTS)
    for j in range(0,N):        
        glVertex2f(xpts[j],ypts[j])

    glEnd()
    glFlush()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    glutInit()
    glutInitWindowSize(700,700)
    glutCreateWindow("My Display")
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB)
    glutDisplayFunc(displayFun)
    initFun()
    glutMainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out it was some simple maths to do. Using a scaling matrix [4,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,1]*[x,y,1]. So after multiplying we get[4x,4y,1]. So if we multiply all points the image is scaled.Learnt this in school. Also the map was inverted. So my program finally looks like this

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

import math

def initFun():
    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0)
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0, 0.0)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluOrtho2D(0,700,0,700)

def displayFun():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0)
    xpts=[]
    ypts=[]
    N=len(newlist)
    for i in range(0,N):
        xpts.append(700+100-float(newlist[i][4])*20)
        ypts.append(700+1300-float(newlist[i][5])*20)

    glBegin(GL_POINTS)
    for j in range(0,N):        
        glVertex2f(xpts[j],ypts[j])

    glEnd()
    glFlush()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    glutInit()
    glutInitWindowSize(700,700)
    glutCreateWindow("My Display")
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB)
    glutDisplayFunc(displayFun)
    initFun()
    glutMainLoop()
```

Comment: so the final pt I get is [4x,4y,1] i.e. (4x,4y). Sorry it was too trivial to be asked here.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `gluOrtho2D` to be `gluOrtho2D(minX,maxX,minY,maxY)` which will position the camera better - based on the image I would try replacing 700 with 300